# How modify the default field validation message in InfoPath form 2013 & Sharepont 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, 2016

How to modify the default field validation message in InfoPath form 2013 now i designed SP 2016 Custom list new item form in Infopath designer 2013
[image]

I went to this path but i did not found above message.
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\INC
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\INC

'The form cannot be submitted because it contains validation errors. Errors are marked with either a red asterisk (required fields) or a red, dashed border (invalid values). Field or group: my: Error: Cannot be blank'

Answer (score 0):

What message you didn't find?

Per my rest, I could find **intlcorestrings.js** in following path:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\INC
```

Or:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\INC\1033
```

Then find strSaveWithErrors in this file:

[image]

Before you change it, remember to back up it.